How to conclude the family $\{\mu_T\}_{T>0}$ is tight?
Abstract: How to conclude the family $\{\mu_T\}_{T>0}$ is (uniformly) tight?
Question: On the page 20 of the lecture note by Martin Hairer, the probability measures
$$
\mu_T(A):=\frac{1}{T}\int^T_0P^s(x_0,A)\,ds,\qquad A\in\mathcal{E},
$$
indexed by $T>0$ are concerned, where $(P^s)_{s\ge0}$ is a transition semigroup of a Feller-Dynkin Markov process $\{X_t\}$, and $x_0\in E$ is a point in a Polish space $E$ with a Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{E}=\mathcal{B}(E)$.
An inequality involving a constant $K>0$, a continuous function $V:E\to[1,\infty)$, and a strictly concave function $\phi:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ increasing to infinity,
$$
\frac{1}{T}\biggl(\operatorname{E}_{x_0}[V(X_T)]-V(x_0)\biggr)\le K-\int_E\phi(V(x))\mu_T(dx)
$$
, valid for any $T>0$, immediately follows from a drift condition (4.1) p.16, of which details are irrelevant of my question. Here, $V$ is additionally assumed to have compact sublevel sets, meaning that, for any $c\ge1$, the preimage $V^{-1}([1,c])$ is a compact subset of $E$. Then, Hairer claims that the uniform tightness of the family $\{\mu_T\}_{T>0}$ 'immediately' follows from the inequality and the compactness of the sublevel sets of $V$, which I cannot figure out why is true.
My Attempt: $\operatorname{E}_{x_0}[V(X_T)]$ and the integral are always positive. Thus, in particular, the both sides of the inequality are bounded for $T>0$.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Boundedness of the integrals
$$
\int_E\phi(V(x))\mu_T(dx),\qquad T>0,
$$
and the fact that for any compact subset $C\overset{\text{cpt}}{\subset}\mathbb{R}$, $(\phi\circ V)^{-1}(C)$ is again a compact subset of $E$ is sufficient for $\{\mu_T\}$ being tight through a proposition suggested in this post.
